# Twitter Bootstrap: nested rows?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Twiter Bootstrap Question: Given the image below, how do I mark up the 3 red containers so that they are fluid and responsive? Can I define a container/row inside a `span*`? Not sure how to tackle such a layout.

[image]

Comment: The doc talks about *Fluid Nesting* in the [Fluid Grid System section](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem)

Comment: Upvote for the neat diagram :o)

Comment: @Sherbrow, I wound up here because the doc doesn't give examples of complex nesting with rows, and isn't entirely clear for this use-case.

Answer (score 7):

Sure you can nest rows inside other spans as deep as you like.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span9">
            <div class="span4"></div>
            <div class="span4"></div>
            <div class="span4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

that should work for your 3 containers inside the 9 row.

Comment: The [docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) recommend wrapping the inner `.span4`s in a `.row-fluid`. Did you intentionally omit it because it is unnecessary in practice, or was it just an oversight?

Comment: @alex Fluid grids works differently: each nested level of columns should add up to 12 columns. This is because the fluid grid uses PERCENTAGES, not pixels, for setting widths. So, the above example is perfect, because it's percentage you can fit 12 inside of 9. I think the bootstrap documentation about this matter is poor.

Answer (score 5):

You can nest row inside row, but then you have to make sure that markup is correct.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span9">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span4">...</div>
                <div class="span4">...</div>
                <div class="span4">...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Follow the link to view working example with this. Try moving vertical bar between HTML and Result view, and you will see responsive layout working then and there. [Three Responsive columns with Twitter Bootstrap](http://jsfiddle.net/rakeshtembhurne/bQNSJ/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this nesting order :

- container-fluid
- row-fluid
- span9
- row-fluid
- span3 span3 span3